# How to compute expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

How do I solve the expected value of this problem, if I have already calculated the pmf?

> Let $X$ be a random variable with cumulative distribution function given
>   below:
>   $$F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & : x < 0
> \\ 1/2 & : 0\leqslant x < 1
> \\ 3/5 & : 1 \leqslant x < 2
> \\ 4/5 & : 2 \leqslant x < 3
> \\ 9/10 & : 3 \leqslant x < 3.5
> \\ 1 & : x \geqslant 3.5
> \end{cases}$$
>   Compute $\mathsf E[X]$

Comment: This is very hard to read.  Please format with $\LaTeX$, using cases, or at least put some extra returns in to break the lines.  Did you look at it after you posted?  A tutorial for formatting math is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  You are asking for free help, you should make it easy for the helpers to read the question.

Answer (score 2):

You probability mass function should look like: $f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
 \Box & : x=0
\\ \Box & : x=1
\\ \Box & : x=2
\\ \Box & : x=3
\\ \Box & : x= 3.5
\\ 0 & : \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$

Since you have filled in the boxes for this, then you can just evaluate:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E[X] &= \sum_{x\in\{0,\,1,\,2,\,3,\,3.5\}} x\, f_X(x)
\\[1ex] & = 0\, f_X(0) + 1\, f_X(1) + 2\, f_X(2) + 3\,f_X(3)+3.5\,f_X(3.5)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You say you have calculated the PMF $p_{X}(x)$ so you can use it to find the expected value:

$$E[X] = \sum_{x}xp_{X}(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

these data are well-suited to using the formula
$$
E[X] = \int_0^{\infty}(1- F_X(x))dx
$$
which here gives:
$$
E[X] = (1-0).\frac12+(2-1).\frac25+(3-2).\frac15 +(3.5-3).\frac1{10} = \frac{23}{20}
$$